# Parsing XML in Elm

Tags: elm

In Elm, how do I parse an XML file? I see lots of example for JSON decoders, but I cannot find an XML decoder.

What alternatives do I have besides REGEX? My XML is pretty simple, and that would work, but I know that's a bad idea.

Comment: I would suggest using a port and a JS library. Not very idiomatic but you'll probably get a result much quicker

Comment: I second to @SimonH as I'm not aware of any library to help you parse XML.  In javascript, there are some known ones available.

Comment: I ended up sending my XML to a port, and then using DOMParser and Xpath to get the fields out of the XML that I was interested in.

Comment: Hey @jm, what about this: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/eeue56/elm-xml/latest ?

Comment: @franzé-jr should put that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty new:

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/eeue56/elm-xml/latest

It seems the commit is from this year(2017). I think this is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Now apparently there is no package for  XML parsing.
But maybe you are interested in this project:

https://github.com/toburger/elm-xml-parser

Answer (score 1):

As of Mid-2022, this seems to be the most maintained and complete solution:

https://github.com/ymtszw/elm-xml-decode